# Inconsistency in signal strength from bluetooth beacons - Kontakt.io

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Recently we purchased a set of 6 beacons from Kontakt. For some reason the values of RSSI averaged over a period of time do not appear consistent. Could someone help me improve my understanding on the following questions?

1. If TxPower of a beacon is -77, what would be the standard deviation in the RSSI value returned by getRSSI() in an iPhone 5 at 1m from the beacon?
2. Would 2 beacons give more or less identical RSSI value, provided that they are placed in same orientation, same configuration(power level & advertising rate), same distance, same relative location from the same phone?
3. Would 2 beacons give same value for getProximity(), provided the above said similar conditions?

Moreover the batteries are draining at different rates even though all of these beacons are having similar settings for TxPower and Advertising Rate.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you should get similar results with identical beacon transmitters configured the same way.  RSSI will vary with radio noise, multipath and obstructions.  If you can keep the physical environment identical between tests, you can eliminate multipath and obstructions from the equation, leaving only radio noise.

I don't have a standard deviation value, but if you are seeing an average RSSI of -77dBm at 1 m (that's what the TxPower calibration value means) then in practice you may see this number vary by about +/- 10dBm.

The radio noise means that nothing is ever perfectly repeatable (questions 2 and 3), but averaged over long periods of time, you should get similar results.

You can read more about beacon ranging here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html

Of course, it is also possible that your multiple beacons are not behaving the same way.  I have no special knowledge of Kontakt beacons, so I cannot speak to that possibility.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and all the work you have done in this field. These were the calibration values I got using the Locate app for 5 beacons kept at 1 m in similar test conditions; -70,-73,-80,-76,-77. In your opinion do you think this variance is normal?

Comment: The variance is higher for lower signal levels, and those are pretty weak signal levels at 1 meter.  A typical transmitter will be around -60 dBM at 1 meter.  The weaker the signal (the more negative the RSSI) the more variance you will see.

Comment: Also, understand that when you do a calibration, all the RSSI measurements are averaged over 30 seconds, which should cause the variance to go way down.   What you are seeing is too much variance IMO.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung . That is what i thought as well. Since, the calibration value shown by your App at 1m is some what consistent, I assume that the beacons must have not been calibrated properly  before kontakt shipped them to me. Hope my assumption is right.